# Upload picture thumbnail preview with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I made a codeigniter function so when a user selects a product picture to upload, it must show as preview picture in the form which the user selected. That way a user can see which picture he selected.

This is a link of how it should look like : https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hymP.jpg

index function in controller:

```
public function index()
  {

    $products = $this->db->get('products');
    ( null !== $products->result() ) ? ( !empty( $products->result() ) ? $products->result() : false ) : false;
     $this->data = ['get_image' => $products]; 
  //Laad kado uploaden view
  $this->load->view('product_form', $data);
  }
```

This is the upload function in the controller code:

```
public function upload() {
        $this->load->library('upload');
        $this->load->library('image_lib');

        $config['upload_path'] = './upload/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|bmp|jpeg';
        $config['max_size']    = '0';
        $config['max_width']  = '0';
        $config['max_height']  = '0';
        $config['encrypt_name']= true;
        $this->upload->initialize($config);


        $products = $this->db->get('products');
        ( null !== $products->result() ) ? ( !empty( $products->result() ) ? $products->result() : false ) : false;
        $this->data = ['get_image' => $products]; 



        if(!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')){
            $error = array('error'=>$this->upload->display_errors());
            $this->load->view('product_form', $error);
        }else{
           //Main image
            $data = $this->upload->data();
            $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
            $config['source_image'] = './upload/'.$data["raw_name"].$data['file_ext'];
            $config['new_image'] = './upload/'.'new_'.$data["raw_name"].$data['file_ext'];
            $config['create_thumb'] = FALSE;
            $config['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
            $config['width'] = 547;
            $config['height'] = 430;

            //Thumb image 
            $dataThumb = $this->upload->data();
            $configThumb['image_library'] = 'gd2';
            $configThumb['source_image'] = './upload/'.$dataThumb["raw_name"].$dataThumb['file_ext'];
            $configThumb['new_image'] = './upload/'.'thumb_'.$dataThumb["raw_name"].$dataThumb['file_ext'];
            $configThumb['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
            $configThumb['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
            $configThumb['width'] = 120;
            $configThumb['height'] = 112;

            $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
            $this->image_lib->resize();

            $this->image_lib->initialize($configThumb);
            $this->image_lib->resize();

            $this-> db-> insert('products', array(
                'user_id' => $_SESSION['user_id'],
                'product_foto' => 'new_'.$data["raw_name"].$data['file_ext'],
                'product_foto_thumb' => 'thumb_'.$dataThumb["raw_name"].$dataThumb['file_ext'],
                'product_naam' => $this->input->post('product_naam'),
                'product_beschrijving' => $this->input->post('product_beschrijving'),
                'ophaal_plaats' => $this->input->post('ophaal_plaats'),
                'category_id' => !empty($this->input->post('category_id')) ? $this->input->post('category_id') : 0,
                'date_created' => date('Y-m-d'),
                'date_updated' => date('Y-m-d')
                ));
            $data['img'] = base_url().
            '/upload/new_'.$data["raw_name"].$data['file_ext'];
            $dataThumb['img'] = base_url().
            '/upload/thumb_'.$dataThumb["raw_name"].$dataThumb['file_ext'];

            header('location:https://kadokado-ferran10.c9users.io//Product/cadeaupagina_aangeboden');



        }
}
```

And this is the view form file of product_foto row:

```
 <div class="image-upload">
                <input id="file-input" type="file" name="userfile"/> 
            <h3>Upload foto </h3>
            <label for="file-input">
                <img src="../images/PLUS.jpg"/>
            </label>
        </div> 
          </td>
         <?php if ($get_image) {
                  echo '<tr>';
                  echo '<td>'.img(array('width' => '120', 'height' => '80',  'src' => 'upload/'.$data->product_foto)).'</td>';
                  echo '<td> Bekijk | Verwijder </td>';
                  echo '</tr>';
              } 
          else { 
                  echo '<tr>';
                  echo '<td> </td>';
                  echo '</tr>';

           }   ?>

        </tr>
```

The 2 erros that I'm getting:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: data

Filename: controllers/Product.php

Line Number: 17

Backtrace:

File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/application/controllers/Product.php
Line: 17
Function: _error_handler

File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

2nd error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: get_image

Filename: views/product_form.php

Line Number: 67

Backtrace:

File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/application/views/product_form.php
Line: 67
Function: _error_handler

File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/application/controllers/Product.php
Line: 21
Function: view

File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

Database information and other information:

```
The map where the picture is stored: upload
The database table name: products
The product picture row is named: product_foto
```

Comment: This isn't so much a question as it is here is my code and some errors. Please ask a specific question and elaborate on what exactly is happening with the script - are the images uploading and resizing?

Comment: Yeh I asked why I can't use the get_image variable in the view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excluding any possible issues with your upload code, the reason you are getting these errors is because you are assigning `$data` to the class scope `$this->data` and not accessing `$this->data` but just `$data` in your view call.

Revised code:

```
public function index()
{

    $products = $this->db->get('products');
    ( null !== $products->result() ) ? (!empty($products->result()) ? $products->result() : false ) : false;
    $data = array('get_image' => $products);
    //Laad kado uploaden view
    $this->load->view('product_form', $data);
}
```

As a side note I don't think you have to access `$this->upload->data();` twice as its the same data. Just assign it to an analogous variable like `$image`.

Comment: so where do I put $this->upload->data(); ?

Comment: You are accessing it twice. I'm not saying you should remove it, it's just redundant to do it twice. It's the same data.

Comment: Also in your view you are accessing $data->product_foto, which should be changed if you take my method to $get_image->product_foto...

Comment: The best thing I can advise is to learn that a class variable has a class scope in that all functions within the class can access it and that a local variable without 'this' can only access variables in the function in which it was assigned.